# No error is thrown but PHP unserialization doesn't succeed

Tags: php, class, serialization

Below is the part of a class, I am currently writing, which should take care of serialization. 
The serialize function works fine and a proper string is produced.
The problem is in the deserialize($data) function.
The proper serialized string is passed to unserialize in the deserialize function.
Unfortunately, the $scl object doesn't contain the expected data. There is no notice or error thrown. The result is that $scl->printData() prints the information but not the content of the class variables. In the future I would like to assign unserialize's result to $this. What am I missing?

```
public function serialize() {
    $serial = serialize($this);
    $df = gzdeflate($serial);
    $b64 = base64_encode($df);
    $ue = urlencode($b64);
    return($ue);
}

public function deserialize($data) {
    $u64 = base64_decode($data);
    $gf = gzinflate($u64);
    $scl = unserialize($gf);   
    if(!$scl)
        echo"Cannot unserialize<br>";
    $scl->printData();
}
function __sleep() {
    return($this);
}
function __wakeup() {
    echo"Waking up";
}
public function printData() {
    echo"Data: <br>
    ID: {$this->ID} <br>
    sID: {$this->sID}<br>
    ...
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__sleep` is [supposed to return an array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) of keys that should be serialized.  You're returning the object.

You *should* be getting the following notice:

> `serialize(): __sleep should return an array only containing the names of instance-variables to serialize.`

If you aren't seeing this, make sure you have error reporting turned all the way up.

Because an object is being returned instead of the array of keys to serialize, the serialized object will end up looking something like:

```
O:3:"Foo":1:{N;}
```

Foo was my test class name, and `N` is unserialized to `null`.  This is why you're losing your data.

If you want to serialize the entire object, either return all of the properties as an array from `__sleep`, or don't implement it at all.  Both it and `__wakeup` are totally optional.

If you are using PHP 5.3, consider [implementing `Serializable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) instead, as it has different side effects that you might find useful if you're trying to run code to handle serialization and unserialization effects

---

It's worth noting that you might find yourself with a **huge** security problem here.  From the URL-encoding, it looks like you might end up passing around serialized objects via forms or URLs.  This is a bad, bad idea, especially if you're building custom sleep/wakeup handling.  It can be a vector for [**malicious users to inject arbritary code**](http://www.suspekt.org/downloads/POC2009-ShockingNewsInPHPExploitation.pdf) (PDF link, start with page 28).  If you absolutely *must* pass around serialized objects in the wild, consider [using *real* encryption](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) on them, and [signing the data with an HMAC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php).

Comment: That worked well :)

I couldn't assign the result of unserialize to $this now is that not possible?

Comment: @jallmer, correct, you can never assign *anything* to `$this` directly, only to properties.  Also, I have added a final section to my question about an important security issue.

Comment: Thank you, I created something like a 'copy constructor' which solved the problem.
Now that it works, I'll deal with the security issue.